# How to properly memoize mapDispatchToProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, memoization

First, here's my HOC:

```
export default function connectField({
         nameProp = 'name',
         valueProp = 'value',
         dispatchProp = 'dispatch'
     }: ConnectOptions) {

    return compose(
        getContext(contextTypes),
        connect((state, ownProps) => {
            const path = [namespace,...getPath(ownProps),...toPath(ownProps[nameProp])];
            const value = getOr('', path, state);
            return {
                [valueProp]: value
            };
        }, (dispatch,ownProps) => { // <----------- mapDispatchToProps
            const path = [...getPath(ownProps),...toPath(ownProps[nameProp])];

            return {
                [dispatchProp]: value => dispatch({type: ActionTypes.Change, payload: {path, value}})
            };

        }, (stateProps, dispatchProps, {[FIELD_PATH]: _, ...ownProps}) => {
            return {...stateProps, ...dispatchProps, ...ownProps}; 
        }, {
            areMergedPropsEqual: (a,b) => {
                let eq = shallowEqual(a,b);
                console.log('areMergedPropsEqual',a,b,eq);
                return eq;
            },
        }),
        withContext(contextTypes, props => {
            return {[FIELD_PATH]: [...getPath(props), props[nameProp]]};
        }),
    );
}
```

In the middle there is my `mapDispatchToProps`. That's causing `areMergedPropsEqual` to return *false* every time because it's creating  a new action creator every time.

I can't figure out how to memoize this bit:

```
value => dispatch({type: ActionTypes.Change, payload: {path, value}})
```

Such that I get back the same function instance every time.

There's some notes [in the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) about "per-instance memoization" which is what I want, but I can't quite make heads or tails of what I'm supposed to do here.

---

To be clear, I know how to memoize a function. However, I don't want a use a big cache with infinite history. It's unnecessary memory consumption. I just need a cache size of 1 like [how reselect does it](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#defaultmemoizefunc-equalitycheck--defaultequalitycheck). The problem is that I can't create the "selector" directly inside `connectField` because that still creates a single shared instance -- i.e., all "connected fields" will share the same cache and they'll overwrite each other, negating the benefit. It has to be *per component instance*. *This is specific to React-Redux's `connect` method*. There's a syntax for it so that you can create your selector at the right spot, and it will only get ran once per instance. I'm just having trouble deciphering the API -- do they expect a function that returns a function that returns an object? Or an object with propnames as keys and functions as values? What does that function return? i.e., the docs aren't clear about all the different variations that are accepted for the `mapDispatchToProps` option.

Comment: @KyleRichardson Read the `mapDispatchToProps` more closely. It takes an "object *or* function". Then it does something different again if the function takes one or two args. And then under "advanced scenarios" it says the function can *also* return a function. So uh... I think I want to pass it a function with one argument and return a function which returns an object. Nevermind, I'll fiddle with it until I figure it out.

Comment: My apologizes for being off base of what you were looking for. I understand the problem now and it's a very interesting one. Still thinking about it... If you come up with a solution, would you please update so that I may view thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have `lodash`, you have a `memoize` function that allow to transform any function into a memoized function. This memoized function will calculate the return value for a given parameter and will then always return this same return value each you supply the same parameter.

You can use it like this for example :

```
import { memoize } from 'lodash'

const makeChangeDispatcher = memoize( (dispatch, path) => 
     value => dispatch({type: ActionTypes.Change, payload: {path, value}})
)

...

    (dispatch,ownProps) => { // <----------- mapDispatchToProps
        const path = [...getPath(ownProps),...toPath(ownProps[nameProp])];

        return {
            [dispatchProp]: makeChangeDispatcher(dispatch, path)
        };

    }

...
```

You can see more infos on the [`lodash` documentation of memoize](https://lodash.com/docs/#memoize)

Comment: I think you missed the point. The part I'm having trouble with is the *per-instance memoization*. You've created a single global memoized function with infinite history. It might work, but my goal is just to avoid re-renders due to prop changes. For that, I only need a history size of 1 but it has to be per-instance.  Sorry, I should have made that more clear.

Comment: Yes, the growing history can be a potential problem, but this is giving you a memoized function based on the dispatch function (wich is always the same) and the path depending on your component props. So you will have function by instances. Mire precisely by path value. So tow component with the same path wilk share the same function (wich is not a problem). What is wrong here ? I have missed the point ^^

Comment: The problem is that the cache needn't grow as the props change. All I'm trying to do is avoid re-renders due to prop changes. If the props don't change, I want back the same dispatch function. If the do change, then a new dispatch function may be returned. For that, I only need a cache size of 1.